# vba frame, image and form control unit of measurement

Tags: excel, vba

i was wondering how i could determine by which unit are frames, image and form sizes are measured?
i am developing an application using vba and excel and i want to fit an image exactly to a frame. i could not determine the unit by which particularly this control is sized.  example: 
frame height is 420
and width is 460 
thank you very much

Comment: Usually the measurement  is in `point` shortened to `pt`.

Comment: For reference, here is the [Microsoft Documentation for the Height and Width properites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/height-width-properties).

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of having an answer, per the [Microsoft Documentation for the Height and Width properites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/height-width-properties) the measurment is in `point` which is `1/72 of an inch` per the [vbe glossary for point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/glossary/vbe-glossary#point).